# GAE (go) push queues rate not enforced

Tags: google-app-engine, go, task-queue

I am trying to have some task in a push queue to be executed at rate of about once a second.
Here is how I defined my `queue.yaml`

```
queue:
- name: default
  rate: 1/s
  bucket_size: 1
  max_concurrent_requests: 1
```

I have a handler (for `/tasks/readalerts`), that enqueues the task:

```
t := taskqueue.NewPOSTTask("/tasks/readalerts", map[string][]string{})
if _, err := taskqueue.Add(context, t, ""); err != nil {
  context.Errorf("%v", err)
}
```

Once I visit the `/tasks/readalerts` the task is indeed being enqueued but it seems like it is running once in about 60ms (this is happening on dev machine, didn't try to deploy it).

What am I missing? shouldn't there be at least 1 second between each task execution?

Thanks,
Itay

Answer (score 0):

OK, seems like what I was missing is setting the `Delay` field of the task.
This will do the trick:

```
t := taskqueue.NewPOSTTask("/tasks/readalerts", map[string][]string{}) 
t.Delay = time.Second
```